# Error in writing to file(JAVA) with Formatter using ActionListener

Tags: java, file, actionlistener, formatter, file-writing

So I'm creating a program to act as a journal, the Journal object is supposed to create a `CreateFile` object which will create a file, write to it the text from the `JTextArea` entry, and close the file.(Essentially saving the file). It's supposed to do this whenever the user presses the save button.

Right now all that happens a blank file is created. Everything except writing to the file is working. Please help to identify and correct the error in writing to my file, below is my code.

Here is the Journal Class

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Formatter;

import javax.swing.*;
public class Journal extends JFrame{
private JTextField date;
public JTextArea entry;
private JButton button;
public static String day, month, year;
private Formatter formatter;
        public Journal(String month, String day, String year){
            this.day=day;
            this.month=month;
            this.year=year;
        //Use parameter so display a date
            String theDate =  month + "/ "+day+"/ "+year;
            Font theFont = new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,20);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        date = new JTextField(theDate+ "     "+"Journal Entry");
        date.setFont(theFont);
        date.setSize(new Dimension(500,50));
        date.setEditable(false);
        //Create a save Button
        button = new JButton("Save Entry");

        add(button,BorderLayout.WEST);
        //Create a place to write the journal entry
        entry = new JTextArea("Enter your entry here");
        entry.setLineWrap(true);
        Font JTFFont = new Font("Serif",Font.PLAIN,14);
        entry.setFont(JTFFont);
        Handlerclass handler = new Handlerclass();
        button.addActionListener(handler);
        add(date,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(entry,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }
private class Handlerclass implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        try {

         CreateFile cf = new CreateFile(month,day,year);
         cf.openFile();
         cf.addRecords();
         cf.closeFile();



        }
        catch(Exception error){
            System.out.println("You have an error");
        }
    }

    }
    public void closeFile(){
        formatter.close();
    }
}
```

Here is the CreateFile  class

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
public class CreateFile extends Journal{

    public CreateFile(String month, String day, String year) {
        super(month, day, year);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private Formatter x;

    public void openFile(){
        try{
            String date = String.format("%s_%s_%s.txt", this.month, this.day, this.year);
            x = new Formatter(date);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

            System.out.println("you have an error");
    }
    }
    public void closeFile(){
        x.close();
    }
    public void addRecords(){

        entry.addKeyListener(
                new KeyListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        x.format(entry.getText());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}

                    @Override
                    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
                }
                );

    }
}
```

Here is the main class

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        //Create new Journal Entry
Journal j = new Journal("3","27","2016");
j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
j.setVisible(true);
j.setSize(500, 500);
j.setResizable(false);
j.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the method that actually writers to your file?

Comment: @PM77-1, in the KeyPressed(KeyEvent event) I have x.format(entry.getText()); this tells the formatter x to write to the file whatever is in the JTextArea entry, at least that's what I have read.

Comment: What is `Formatter`? `Journal`? What does `Formatter.format()` do?

Comment: @EJP see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#Formatter(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem in your implementation is, that the method `CreateFile::addRecords` does not write to the file. Only a `KeyListener` is registered. After that the `Formatter` is closed immediately. Now it was tried to write to the file on every keypress, but this is not possible, because the `Formatter` is closed.

Additional advice: It is much better to print the Stacktrace (`err.printStackTrace`) in a catch of an exception. So you are able to find out, what is going wrong and where.

Next point (`CreateFile` extending `Journal`): Sometimes it is better to use the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) to [separate concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and avoid subclasses.

Here an implementation where your problem is fixed and the other points are respected:

```js
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Journal extends JFrame{
    public Journal(String month, String day, String year){
        String theDate =  month + "/ "+day+"/ "+year;
        Font theFont = new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,20);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JTextField dateField = new JTextField(theDate+ "     "+"Journal Entry");
        dateField.setFont(theFont);
        dateField.setSize(new Dimension(500,50));
        dateField.setEditable(false);
        JButton button = new JButton("Save Entry");
        JTextArea entry = new JTextArea("Enter your entry here");
        entry.setLineWrap(true);
        Font JTFFont = new Font("Serif",Font.PLAIN,14);
        entry.setFont(JTFFont);
        String date = String.format("%s_%s_%s.txt", month, day, year);
        try {
            button.addActionListener(new SaveHandler(date, entry));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        add(button,BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(dateField,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(entry,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

```js
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Formatter;

class SaveHandler implements ActionListener {

    private String date;
    private JTextArea entry;
    public SaveHandler(String date, JTextArea entry) throws FileNotFoundException {
        this.date = date;
        this.entry = entry;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            new Formatter(date).format(entry.getText()).close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```